# How to make passwords case insensitive?

Tags: 7, users

it appears as passwords in Drupal 7 are case sensitive. Is there a way to make them case insensitive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The password is stored as a hash, upper/lowercase differences result in a different hash.

The only possible way I can think of is if you always convert the password to upper/lowercase before it is used, both when registering and when logging in. But that sounds error prone to me.

Also, if the passwords are already stored in the database, then there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Since doing this severly limits the number of possible passwords, it would also make your passwords much easier to hack. There's a reason all password prompts elsewhere (both in operating systems and webapps) are case sensitive.

Comment: While this does not at all answer the question, it is a very good point.

Answer (score 0):

The password is stored as a hash, upper/lowercase differences result in a different hash.

There is nearly no other ways to make it work except making it in either lower or upper case before we save it.

You can use javascript or add another **form submit handler** to convert the pass to either lower or upper case before it gets saved to database.